# Custom HTTP server. Checking if socket input stream is empty using PushbackInputStream. Unread method won't work

Tags: java, sockets, http, stream

I'm implementing a custom HTTP server and I'm using the `PushbackInputStream` class to check if my socket input stream is not empty. However, unread method won't work. I would appreciate your help.

```
PushbackInputStream pushbackInputStream = new PushbackInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), 1);

int singleByte;
if((singleByte = pushbackInputStream.read()) != -1) {
  pushbackInputStream.unread(singleByte);

  //  do stuff
}
```

Comment: What are the symptoms of 'the method won't work'? An exception? An unexpected behavior? What are you expecting and what do you get?

Comment: You don't *need* this. HTTP is well-enough defined that you can tell where the end of a request is. See RFC 2616 and successors, specifically the parts about content-length and transfer-encoding.

Comment: @Roman Puchkovskiy, the first char in the request String always gets eaten.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include important details like that.  Make your question as close to a [mcve] as you can, including inputs, outputs, and expected behavior.

Comment: Of course it gets eaten. It's there in the `PushbackInputStream`, but you throw that away when you exit this method, because it's a local variable, or else you don't keep reading from it in this method. But I repeat that you most certainly do not need this.

Comment: @EJP sorry, I don't think I've understood your response

Comment: I made it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm implementing a custom HTTP server and I'm using the `PushbackInputStream` class to check if my socket input stream is not empty.

No you're not. You're using it to detect end of stream.

> However, `unread()` method won't work.

It *does* work, but only *if you keep reading from the* `PushBackInputStream`. It doesn't magically stuff the byte back into the underlying `Socket` input stream.

However there is nothing in HTTP that requires detecting 'empty stream'. You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP, and specifically for this purpose a good knowledge of the provisions about content length and transfer-encoding.

You don't need this.